# c# Parse XML and store nodes to grid

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

This is the `XML` I get from a request:

```
<ODM xmlns:.....>
    <Data DID="Mdid">
         <SubjectData SubjectKey="1">
               <SRef Location="Loc1"/>
               <SEventData SEventID="SID1">
                    <FormData FormID="FID1">
                          <ItemGroupData ItemGroupID="IGID1">
                                <ItemData ItemID="IID1" IsNull="Yes"/>
                                <ItemData ItemID="IID2" IsNull="Yes"/>
                                <ItemData ItemID="IID3" IsNull="Yes"/>
                                <ItemData ItemID="IID4" Value="cvs"/>
                          </ItemGroupData>
                    </FormData>
                </SEventData>
          </SubjectData>
     </Data>
     <Data DID="Zdid">
           <SubjectData SubjectKey="2">
               <SRef Location="Loc2"/>
               <SEventData SEventID="SID2">
                    <FormData FormID="FID2">
                          <ItemGroupData ItemGroupID="IGID2">
                                <ItemData ItemID="IID11" Value="xcs"/>
                                <ItemData ItemID="IID12" IsNull="Yes"/>
                                <ItemData ItemID="IID13" IsNull="Yes"/>
                                <ItemData ItemID="IID14" Value="zfv"/>
                          </ItemGroupData>
                    </FormData>
                </SEventData>
          </SubjectData>
     </Data>
          ........
</ODM>
```

How I can store the Items and their Values in a grid from specific `Data`, `SubjectData`, `SEventData`, `FormData`, `ItemGroupData` or `ItemData`?

This is what I have tried for `ItemData` but it returns `null`:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(response.RawXMLString());

var items = xdoc.Descendants("ItemData")
           .ToDictionary(i => (string)i.Attribute("ItemID"),
                         i => (string)i.Attribute("Value"));
```

**Example**

Items of "Mdid" Data (will be the same for `SubjectKey` == 1, `SEventID` = "SID1" etc. But Items of "Zdid" Data will be diferrent because it will probably contain different `ItemData` ):

```
 ItemID    |    IsNull   |  Value
  IID1     |      Yes    |
  IID2     |      Yes    |
             ......
```

**EDIT**

Both solutions unfortunately didn't work... In case it helps here is a sample xml I am working on:[link](http://medidatarwsnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_resources.html#subjectdatasetrequest)

Comment: It's not clear exactly what output you want here, can you explain that please?

Comment: Your xml has a number of levels of nesting. Maybe you can show a mock up of what the grid might look like? It is hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Added an example. Hope its clearer now

Comment: Well it's a little more clearer, but now you've complicated things by saying `Mdid` is different to `Zdid` without saying what the difference is and how you would want to handle it.

Comment: @DavidG "Zdid" will have different set of  <ItemData

Comment: In what way are they different? Do you want them combined into a single grid?

Comment: The grid will have 3 columns: `ItemID`, `IsNull`, `Value` and it will get the rows from `Data` == "MDid" or `Data` == "ZDid" or from other level

Comment: So in the grid you will never know if the row has come from a Mdid or a zdid section?

Comment: No need. It will get the input from the user and will produce the specific output. Question like "`ItemData` of  `Data` with `DID` == "Zdid" "

Comment: The root node has a `xmlns`. You must specify this namespace in your queries.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, this code will parse the `ItemData` elements into a list, but will lost the context of whether they came from a `Mdid` or `Zdid` section:

First a class to hold the item data:

```
public class ItemData
{
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public string IsNull { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the Linq to process the XML:

```
var items = xdoc
    .Descendants("Data")
    .Where(d => d.Attribute("DID").Value == "Mdid") //These lines can be added
    .Descendants("ItemData")                        //to filter if you need them
   .Select(i => new ItemData
   {
       ItemID = (string)i.Attribute("ItemID"),
       IsNull = (string)i.Attribute("IsNull"),
       Value = (string)i.Attribute("Value")
   });
```

In case you need to include the namespace, this is how you do it:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3";
```

And then prefix the names with `ns. For example:

```
.Descendants(ns+"ItemData")
```

Comment: Tried that approach but I get "Enumeration yielded not results"

Comment: It works fine against the XML you show above. For example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/f5KCmo

Comment: It doesn't work with my data... can you check the edited OP?

Comment: I've added an edit to show you how to use namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

If it is failing you may have more the one ItemData with same value.  Try following :

```
           XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> items = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ItemData")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("ItemOID"), y => y.Attribute("IsNull") != null ? "Null" : (string)y.Attribute("Value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            //if above fails tgry following
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> items2 = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ItemData")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("ItemOID"), y => y.Attribute("IsNull") != null ? "Null" : (string)y.Attribute("Value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            //or use two level dictionary
            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> items3 = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "SubjectData")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Attribute("SubjectKey"), y => y.Descendants().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "ItemData")
                    .GroupBy(a => (string)a.Attribute("ItemOID"), b => b.Attribute("IsNull") != null ? "Null" : (string)b.Attribute("Value"))
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: No luck either... Here is a sample of my xml response: http://medidatarwsnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_resources.html#subjectdatasetrequest